# How can I copy a file on a network share using a different login with powershell or batch file?

Tags: windows, network-shares, powershell, batch-file, file-transfer

I have a file in a shared location that I want to copy over to my local hard drive. However I will not be running as a user that has access to the share. So I want to be able to authenticate under a different login (one which does have the permission) and copy the files.

Is there anything I can do to achieve this?

I tried this command (in a ps1 file):

```
runas /user:domain\username "copy-file $shareloc $destloc"
```

I get this error:

```
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - copy-file \\share\some\dir\file.exe C:\dir\file.exe
2: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

How can I copy a file on a network share using a different login with powershell or batch file?

Comment: is the file actually in the location it is copying from ?, e.g   \\share\some\dir\file.exe

Comment: just use "cmd copy ..." or "cmd /k copy ..." in front - [found here](https://codeimprovements.wordpress.com/2012/03/26/runas-cant-execute-the-copy-command-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a batch file, you can connect to the share with the user option:

```
net use x: \\share\some /user:username password
```

then do the copy command as you normally would (either using the drive letter, or using the UNC as in the question), then disconnect from the share with

```
net use x: /d
```

(You can put * in place of the password to be prompted for it.)

Disclaimer: I'm not sure if this works in a domain.